# Play-enhancer in Play Framework 2.5.X does'nt work

Tags: playframework-2.3

I upgraded all my installation and now i must create getters/setters otherwise update form or create not working and ebean update does'nt work, all my fields are public

I cleaned files delete target change scala version ...

but does'nt work anymore, it is a big issue,

any idea ?

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
```

and in build.sbt

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
.enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayEnhancer)
```

Comment: did you figure out how to fix this issue? I have exactly the same problem with sbt-place-enhacer v1.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

[Setting up play-enhancer in play 2.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayEnhancer#setting-up)

In play 2.5, play enhancer is seperate sbt plugin

Comment: I have the good configuration in old version it has already the plugin i just upgraded to 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.0 both does'nt work :  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0"), the lib is present in dependencies but not still not working PS i use play-authenticate 8.3

Comment: @cyril, in your build.sbt file did you enable it?
ex:
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayEnhancer)

Comment: yes nothing change, it is very very strange i edit my post thank you !

Comment: it is working now very strange i have a other project in same workspace no enhancer activaed but working....

Comment: finally problem still here i i delete all getters i have this problem : [CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'label' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)]